# Create MediaStream from ReadableStream

Tags: node.js, webrtc, node-streams, mediastream, simple-peer

I'm using [puppeteer-stream](https://github.com/Flam3rboy/puppeteer-stream/) to get a stream of a browser controlled by Node, running on a server. I am able to write this stream out to a file with no issues.

I wanted to stream this stream via WebRTC to a browser *(basically to see what the browser is running in realtime)*. For webrtc, I'm trying to use [simple-peer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-peer) since it has ready bindings for Node as well as the browser-side.

However, when I try to pass this stream to simple-peer, I get the following error:

```
/Users/my_user/my_project/node_modules/simple-peer/index.js:286
    stream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
           ^

TypeError: stream.getTracks is not a function
    at Peer.addStream (/Users/my_user/my_project/node_modules/simple-peer/index.js:286:12)
```

This is because the Stream I have is a **ReadableStream**, but simple-peer *(or most webrtc libs)* expects a **MediaStream**.

How can I convert a realtime **ReadableStream** into a **MediaStream** that can be used with WebRTC? I found examples to convert **MediaStreams** into **ReadableStreams** [such as here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mediastream-to-webm) but not vice versa.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I am still looking for the same problem and still can't find the solution. Have you managed to solve it? If so, how did you do it?